# How to achieve ellipsize(Three dots) in List item of Android List Item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hi my ListView's list items layout is as below: Also attaching Image that shows the output of this layout [image: Output Image of Layout]. 
In the above  output image we can see the text present in  2nd line over laps with right aligned TextView. I want 3 dots to be placed at the end of Text with out overlap.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/abbr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue ?

Thanks in Adavnce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these layout attributes for your TextView

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

This tells android you want your textview to be ellipsized at the end (add the 3 dots to the end of the text) and that you don't want your text to wrap to the next line (by setting the max lines).

The only thing you would need to then is make sure your TextViews don't overlap (the cri... portion). There are a number of ways to do this.

1. Move your abbr TextView to above your other TextViews and add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/abbr"` to your non-abbr TextViews
2. Redo your layout in general to make sure there is no overlap, using LinearLayouts would help achieve this with the benefit of things like weight.
3. Dynamically setting your widths once you know your window size.